# NN with different activation function

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, r

What is an easy way to tweak a popular NN package and use my own coded activation function, instead of its internal activation functions like ReLU or sigmoid? Preference is with R code tweaks, and if not-then in Python.

Comment: [pytorch custom activation function](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/customize-an-activation-function/1652/14)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in [Keras](https://keras.io/) and Python:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

def custom_activation(x):
    return abs(x)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, 
            input_dim=20,
            activation=custom_activation))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `K.abs` instead, so that it can use automatic differentiation for backpropagation?